# Trying to create an array from my nested struct

Tags: arrays, json, xcode

My json is in a file in the Application Bundle.  I have the following corresponding nested struct. There are many members of the  article array in the json and I'm only interested in the content of the each article.

```
struct Complaint: Codable {
    var status: String
    var totalResults: String
    struct article: Codable {
        struct idName: Codable {
            var id: String
            var name: String
        }
        var author: String
        var title: String
        var description: String
        var url: String
        var urlToImage: String
        var content: String
    }
}
```

I'm able to read the file and decode using the struct as follows:

```
let items2 = Bundle.main.decode([Complaint].self, from: "complaint.json")
```

Now I want to end up with an array of Strings of the content.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the contents of your json file into https://app.quicktype.io and it will confirm if your struct is correct for the given json code.  My gut feeling is that the struct should be as follows:

```
struct Complaint: Codable {
    var status: String
    var totalResults: String
    var articles: [Article]

    struct Article: Codable {
        struct idName: Codable {
            var id: String
            var name: String
        }
        var author: String
        var title: String
        var description: String
        var url: String
        var urlToImage: String
        var content: String
    }
}
```